# Where is -lEGL -lGLESv2

Tags: c, opengles

I'm trying to install an [OpenVG library](https://github.com/ajstarks/openvg), but when I start to make it I get the error.

```
...
gcc -L/opt/vc/lib -lEGL -lGLESv2 -ljpeg -shared -o libshapes.so oglinit.o libshapes.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lEGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLESv2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:35: recipe for target 'library' failed
make: *** [library] Error 1
```

I'm suspecting that this problem is because I just changed to Stretch ,but unfortunately I would rather keep using this library. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What's in your /opt/vc/lib? They should provide the EGL/GLES libraries. Try update your firmware and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These libraries were renamed to `libbrcmEGL.so` and `libbrcmGLESv2.so` on Stretch, in order to reduce the risk of conflicting with their libgles2-mesa-dev counterparts. Edit the Makefiles to say `-lbrcmEGL -lbrcmGLESv2` instead.

In fact, somebody already did that and [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/ajstarks/openvg/pull/60/files).